# How to get discrete values and query on them in Prometheus/Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a gauge with discrete values from 0 to 5.  During the day the gauge can have any value, but at a specific time each day, it's value is either 4 or 5.
The gauge has a label with different application name like

```
mygauge{app=app1}
mygauge{app=app2}
...
mygauge{app=app100}
```

I would like to get the apps where the value of the gauge was always 5 at the specific time (lets say 5pm) on each day in the last week.

Is it possible to extract via prometheus?

Answer (score 1):

Go to prometheus, open graph page, tune in required time of the day and paste this query:

```
mygauge == 5 and mygauge offset 1d == 5  and mygauge offset 2d == 5 and ...
```

(repeat and til 6d)
If you'll see metrics for some apps, this are apps you looking for. If no values - there are no apps satisfying the condition.